# Jacoco : JUnit test cases are mandatory?

Tags: junit4, jacoco

I am planning  to implement Jacoco in my project. So just wanted to know that is  it mandatory that i have to write Junit test cases or i can use existing regression test cases in other tools such as selenium or soap-Ui Pro.

Answer (score 1):

In another words i wanted to know whether we can get code coverage using black box test cases. And the answer is yes. To get coverage for black box test cases using jacoco, you will have to inject jacoco agent in you AUT shell/bat application start up file. Which in turn creates a jacoco.exec file containing information about coverage.Pass this file to jacoco API ReportGenerator and you can create html reports about coverage.